# How to resolve conflict for two unmerged commits in Git?

Tags: git, github

There are two commits which have conflicts. neither of them has been merged, then how to resolve the conflict and rebase the master branch?

I am only working on my own branch right now, and my commit have conflicts with another dev's commit. I cannot get her code from remote so I cannot use mergetool to resolve the conflict.

New to version control, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us about who made the commits, which branches they're on, etc?

Comment: Another developer and I made separate commits. We have our own branches and we wants to merge them into the remote branch.

Comment: OK, so you have your own branches with different names, not just your own separate copies of `master`?

Comment: I am only working on one branch right now, and my commit have conflicts with another dev's commit. I cannot get her code from remote so I cannot use mergetool to resolve the conflict.

Comment: If your colleague has already pushed to remote, you should be able to `git fetch` it ok. Does that fail, or is it just `pull` that complains about the merge conflict?

Comment: Both of us already pushed. When the team leader tried to merge the commits to the main tree, there were conflicts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23904/discussion-between-useless-and-helen)

Answer (score 1):

From the [git documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge):

You'll see conflict markers like these in the files where there's a conflict. Edit your file according to what it SHOULD be and delete the markers.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

Or you could use a merge tool. You'll get a great gui showing you the confilcting parts of each commit. You'll have to have a merge tool installed. If you do, After git prompts you of a merge conflict type:

```
git mergetool
```

If you don't have a mergetool installed, install one!

I use meld. [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). You can install it using

```
apt-get meld
```

Other good options are [Vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) [kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools)